# The way to split a xaml file to few pages

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found out a having one big XAML it's not good idea. So that's why i'm gonna split it to few less

```
<TabItem Header="Home">How to import here Home.xaml</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="Tools">Tools.xaml</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="Settings">Settings.xaml</TabItem>
```

Home.xaml

```
<TextBlock>Content of Home</TextBlock>
```

I know a user control is fine but it is to much complicated to my app which is simple

Comment: Perhaps you can use data templates and put them in the resource files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a UserControl to a TabItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231950/adding-a-usercontrol-to-a-tabitem)

Comment: if you agree that is a duplicate better if you just close your Q instead of remove it.